# How to program Arduino to take and save two keypad inputs in separate variables?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Trying to make a simple Arduino adder but I am having trouble with the programming. I am not sure where I made a mistake. Any help would be much appreciated.

The user would have to enter two numbers n a keypad and their sum would be displayed on an LCD. Each of the two numbers entered by the user are stored in their variables respectively. The problem is that after entering the first number the program automatically plugs in 0 (since no key is pressed at that moment) for the second variable. I have tried 'if', 'while' and 'do while' statements to eliminate NO_KEY but none of these seem to be working.

The question is if there is a way to store a number entered by the user in a variable and not let the program overwrite it with 0 because no key is being pressed at that moment. Or also, to not let the Arduino receive any more inputs from the keypad after a key is pressed (maybe disable the keypad somehow)...

If you are willing to spend some time on looking over the code, the website linked [here](https://circuits.io/circuits/2498139-calculator/embed#breadboard) contains both the code and the whole lab setup.

```
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd (7,8,9,10,11,12);
int backLight(13);


int Addition(int x, int y){
    int z;
    z = x+y;
    lcd.setCursor(8,0);
    lcd.write(z);
}

void setup() {

}

const byte rows =4;
const byte cols =3;

char keys[rows][cols]={
    {'1','2','3'},
    {'4','5','6'},
    {'7','8','9'},
    {'*','0','#'}
};

byte rowPins[rows] = {0,1,2,3};
byte colPins[cols] = {4,5,6};

Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, rows, cols);


void loop(){

    int a;
    int b;

    a = keypad.getKey();
    if (a != NO_KEY){

        do {
            b = keypad.getKey();
        }while (b == NO_KEY);

        pinMode (backLight, OUTPUT);
        digitalWrite(backLight, HIGH);
        lcd.begin(16,2);
        lcd.clear();

        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.write(a);

        lcd.setCursor(2,0);
        lcd.write("+");

        lcd.setCursor(4,0);
        lcd.write(b);

        lcd.setCursor(6,0);
        lcd.write("=");

        Addition(a,b);
        delay(10000);

    }

}
```

Comment: The circuit is probably irrelevant, but the code is not, so please edit your question to include the actual code. Questions with links to code are worthless, since who knows when the links will disappear. Please take some time and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a section of code like this:

```
do {
    b = keypad.getKey();
} while (b = NO_KEY);
```

In the while condition, it looks like you're assigning `NO_KEY` to `b` with `(b = NO_KEY)`, instead of checking equality with `(b == NO_KEY)`. The assignment returns true, hence the loop won't exit.
It should look like this:

```
do {
    b = keypad.getKey();
} while (b == NO_KEY);
```

For the Addition problem, your keymap contains chars rather than ints. So a and b should be of type char, and you can use `atoi()` to convert them to ints:

```
char a;
char b;

// ...assign values to a and b as you already do...

Addition(atoi(a), atoi(b)); // use atoi() (ascii to int) to pass integer values to Addition
```

Alternatively, you could change your keymap to be:

```
int keys[rows][cols]={
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
    {7, 8, 9},
    {'*',0,'#'}
};
```

and used `lcd.print(a, DEC)` to print the values. Then you'd have no need of `atoi()` and it'd be cleaner in my opinion.
Addition function:

```
Addition(int x, int y) {
    int z;
    z = x+y; // z is now the integer sum
    lcd.setCursor(8,0);
    lcd.print(z, DEC); // print the decimal value of z (default is ascii)
}
```

Comment: Alright. So thanks to you naffarn its halfway working now... for some reason it displays letters as the sum instead of numbers

Comment: in fact it is displaying the sum as the letter in the alphabet  that holds the numbers place. - For instance 1+0=a(1 is the first letter) 1+1=b(two as the second letter) 2+2=d and so on...

Comment: Your keymap has char values in it, not integers. When you press a button, you are assigning the ASCII value of that char to the int variable. when you call `lcd.write(a)`, it writes the character that is represented by the ASCII value in a. However, when you perform the addition, you are adding the ASCII values. `'1 '+ '1' = 49 + 49 = 98 = 'b'`. To change this, I'd use an atoi function when adding.

Comment: I've added code into my answer above to show one way of making it print correctly

Comment: Thank you very much!! I wound have never figured this out by myself.

Comment: Glad I could help,  it's a really weird coincidence that adding ascii values of single digit numbers gives their corresponding letter in the alphabet haha, haven't seen that before

Comment: yeah, it is really weird... Now, I have moved on to making a calculator that can actually perform all 4 basic operations but for somehow my if - else - else if statements got  little messed up. The program either runs the if statement if the first criteria is true or the else statement if the first criteria isn't met, but it keeps ignoring the else if statements. I'm thinking, can it be that each time you use else if you have to have a different test as the criteria? Or what could the problem be?

Comment: https://circuits.io/circuits/2516816-full-calculator/embed#breadboard

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, but I can tell you that everything in the last column except A is bugged. The B, C and D keys all map to the leftmost key (4,7,* respectively). I'd say it's a problem with your keymap. If you can't figure it out, go ahead and post a different question, as these are 2 different issues. The problem is definitely with your mapping though, those keys are being read incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I know its a different topic and I would post a different question but stack exchange wants me to wit at least 3 days before posting another question. I thought it might just be an easy answer for you since you solved all my other problems   so easily anyways. Thank you though. I thought it was a keypead too at first but I couldnt find any problems with it so i thought it must be something else.

Comment: Yeah,  I'm great with C code,  less great with arduinos. Maybe look at a mapping tutorial